# How can I send data from a form to a webhook (zappier)?

Tags: webhooks, form-data, custom-wordpress-pages

I made a custom theme in WP, and in one page I have this form:

```
<form id="contactform">
        <input id="contactName" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Your Name" required>
        <input id="contactEmail" name="address" type="email" placeholder="Your E-mail" required>
        <textarea id="contactMessage" name="message" placeholder="Your Message" required></textarea>
        <button id="contactSubmitButton" type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

At the moment I send the form data by email to a specific address and redirect to a thank-you page. I would like to send it to a zap.

The code I use for the current functionality is the following:

```
<script>
(function($){
    $('#contactform').submit( function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var endpoint = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php');?>';
        var form = $('#contactform').serialize();
        var formdata = new FormData;
        formdata.append('action','contactus');
        formdata.append('nonce', '<?php echo wp_create_nonce('uglyrg');?>');
        formdata.append('contactus', form);
        $.ajax(endpoint, {

            type:'POST',
            data:formdata,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,

            success: function(res){
            document.location.href = "../thank-you-for-contacting-us/";
            },
            error: function(err){
                alert(err.responseJSON.data);
            }
        })
    })
})(jQuery)
</script>
```

and the code in the functions.php file:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_contactus','contactus_form');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_contactus','contactus_form');

function contactus_form()
{
    if( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['nonce'],'ascoul'))
    {
        wp_send_json_error('Nonce is incorrect', 401);
        die();
    }
    $formdata = [];
    wp_parse_str($_POST['contactus'], $formdata);
    // admin email
    $admin_email = get_option('admin_email');
    // Email headers
    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8';
    $headers[] = 'From: Website <' . $admin_email . '>';
    $headers[] = 'Reply-to:' . $formdata['address'];
    // Who are we sending the email to?
    $send_to = $admin_email;
    // Subject
    $subject = "Enquiry from " . $formdata['name'];
    // Message
    $message = '';
    foreach($formdata as $index => $field)
    {
        $message .= '<strong>' . $index . '</strong>: ' . $field . '<br />';
    }
    try {
        if(wp_mail($send_to, $subject, $message, $headers))
        {
            wp_send_json_success('Form submitted!');
        }
        else {
            wp_send_json_error('An error occured!');
        }
    } catch (Exception $e)
    {
            wp_send_json_error($e->getMessage());
    };
}
```

I have put so much effort, in creating a custom theme, and I would like to avoid switching to a WP theme that supports Elementor and other plugins that support webhooks without any coding.

I would appreciate your help.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I did find a solution, finally:

```
//send to zappier

    $url="hook"

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $formdata
    ));

    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```